# How to parse nested XML file in Javascript with browser independent?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, nested

I have **XML** file I want it to parse in Javascript and display the contents on HTML file. I have tried following javascript code-

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            var txt = "<ul>";
            var x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CONTROLLER"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
}
            txt = txt + "</ul>";
            document.getElementById("myTD").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","console1.xml",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When I give **TITLE** in place of **CONTROLLER** it list all **TITLE** present in XML. But I want it to read the XML in **nested** way. My XML file is as -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTROLLERS>
    <CONTROLLER>
        <TITLE>User</TITLE>
        <ACTION>
            <LABEL>Create User</LABEL>
            <HTTP_METHOD>POST</HTTP_METHOD>
            <PARAMS>
               <PARAM><NAME>email</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>user_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>first_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>last_name</NAME></PARAM>
            </PARAMS>
        </ACTION>
        <ACTION>
            <LABEL>Update User</LABEL>
            <HTTP_METHOD>POST</HTTP_METHOD>
            <PARAMS>
               <PARAM><NAME>id</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>email</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>user_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>first_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>last_name</NAME></PARAM>
            </PARAMS>
        </ACTION>
    </CONTROLLER>
    <CONTROLLER>
        <TITLE>Admin</TITLE>
        <ACTION>
            <LABEL>Create Admin</LABEL>
            <HTTP_METHOD>POST</HTTP_METHOD>
            <PARAMS>
               <PARAM><NAME>email</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>admin_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>password</NAME></PARAM>
            </PARAMS>
        </ACTION>
    </CONTROLLER>
</CONTROLLERS>
```

So please help me to parse the nested XML file in javascript.